What is the grammar for balanced parentheses and square brackets?
I found this question here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOFWP_m9t7k
46 minutes 10 seconds.
My first try was to just have square and normal parentheses like so
S->SS|(S)|[S]|€
But this was probably not the expected solution as it accepts ([]) which is not correct. My second try was this
S->SS|[S]|T
T->TT|(T)|€
Is this grammar correct for balanced parantheses for normal and square brackets?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111497/writing-a-grammar-for-matching-parenthesis-and-brackets-is-this-a-correct-answer
